# In what way is Jorge Amado's The Violent Land a modernist novel?

Tags: history-of-literature, portuguese-language, jorge-amado, the-violent-land

The Wikipedia article about Jorge Amado's [*The Violent Land* / *Terras do Sem Fim*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Violent_Land) describes this work as "a Brazilian Modernist novel". The corresponding [Portuguese](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terras_do_Sem-Fim), [French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Terres_du_bout_du_monde) and [Italian](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terre_del_finimondo) Wikipedia articles make no mention of modernism.

The novel was published in 1943, so it can be argued that it is an early example of [late modernism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_modernism#Late_modernism). However, the Wikipedia article about literary modernism does not discuss Amado or any other South-American authors, and the Wikipedia article about [Jorge Amado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jorge_Amado) merely points out that he was an author "of the modernist school" without providing references on Amado's modernism.

Hence my question: what characteristics of *The Violent Land* make this work a modernist novel? Or is the claim incorrect?